# Unable to load ROS2 workspace into CLion

Tags: ros2, clion, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get Ros2 to work with my copy of CLion using [this guide on the Discussion Forums](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-clion/2508/2), but have been having no luck. I was wondering if there were more up-to-date instructions, since these were written in 2017. Or if I'm inadvertently messing something up. Probably the latter.

Before we start, this is all on Ubuntu version 18.04 LTE, running on a Lenovo ThinkPad P52.

So first off, the step for compilation seems to have a couple stderrors for me. I don't *think* they're the cause of my pain, but I'm a bit new to this, so who knows!

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/dde06afe63091e2444be2afd40bf39a4

Second, he has me create a top-level CMakeLists.txt file:

```
add_subdirectory(src/ament/googletest/googlemock)
add_subdirectory(src/ament/googletest/googletest)
add_subdirectory(src/ament/uncrustify_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/eProsima/Fast-CDR)
add_subdirectory(src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/test)
add_subdirectory(src/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/osrf_testing_tools_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/src)
add_subdirectory(src/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/src/memory_tools)
add_subdirectory(src/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/src/test_runner)
add_subdirectory(src/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/test)
add_subdirectory(src/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/test/cmake)
add_subdirectory(src/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/test/memory_tools)
add_subdirectory(src/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/test/test_runner)
add_subdirectory(src/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/test_osrf_testing_tools_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/ament_cmake_ros/ament_cmake_ros)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/actionlib_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/common_interfaces)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/diagnostic_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/geometry_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/nav_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/sensor_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/shape_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/std_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/std_srvs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/stereo_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/trajectory_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/common_interfaces/visualization_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/console_bridge_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/composition)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/demo_nodes_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/demo_nodes_cpp_native)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/dummy_robot/dummy_map_server)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/dummy_robot/dummy_robot_bringup)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/dummy_robot/dummy_sensors)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/image_tools)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/intra_process_demo)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/lifecycle)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/logging_demo)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/pendulum_control)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/demos/pendulum_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/example_interfaces)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/examples/rclcpp/minimal_action_client)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/examples/rclcpp/minimal_action_server)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/examples/rclcpp/minimal_client)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/examples/rclcpp/minimal_composition)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/examples/rclcpp/minimal_publisher)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/examples/rclcpp/minimal_service)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/examples/rclcpp/minimal_subscriber)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/examples/rclcpp/minimal_timer)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/geometry2)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/geometry_experimental)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/test_tf2)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2_bullet)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2_eigen)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2_geometry_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2_kdl)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2_py)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2_ros)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2_sensor_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/geometry2/tf2_tools)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/kdl_parser/kdl_parser)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/kdl_parser/kdl_parser_py)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/launch/apex_rostest/apex_launchtest_cmake)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/launch/launch_testing)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/libyaml_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/message_filters)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/orocos_kdl)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/orocos_kdl/doc)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/orocos_kdl/examples)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/orocos_kdl/models)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/orocos_kdl/src)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/orocos_kdl/tests)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/poco_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rclcpp/rclcpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rclcpp/rclcpp_action)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rclcpp/rclcpp_lifecycle)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl_interfaces/action_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl_interfaces/builtin_interfaces)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl_interfaces/composition_interfaces)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl_interfaces/lifecycle_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl_interfaces/rcl_interfaces)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl_interfaces/rosgraph_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl_interfaces/test_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl_logging/rcl_logging_log4cxx)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl_logging/rcl_logging_noop)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rclpy/rclpy)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl/rcl)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl/rcl_action)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl/rcl_lifecycle)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl/rcl/test)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcl/rcl_yaml_param_parser)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcpputils)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rcutils)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/realtime_support/rttest)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/realtime_support/rttest/examples)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/realtime_support/tlsf_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw_connext/rmw_connext_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw_connext/rmw_connext_dynamic_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw_connext/rmw_connext_shared_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/rmw_fastrtps_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/rmw_fastrtps_dynamic_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/rmw_fastrtps_shared_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw_implementation/rmw_implementation)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw_opensplice/rmw_opensplice_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw/rmw)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw/rmw_implementation_cmake)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rmw/rmw/test)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/robot_state_publisher)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/ros1_bridge)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_dds/rosidl_generator_dds_idl)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_defaults/rosidl_default_generators)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_defaults/rosidl_default_runtime)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_python/python_cmake_module)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_python/rosidl_generator_py)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl/rosidl_adapter)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl/rosidl_cmake)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl/rosidl_generator_c)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl/rosidl_generator_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl/rosidl_parser)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl/rosidl_typesupport_interface)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_connext/connext_cmake_module)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_connext/rosidl_typesupport_connext_c)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_connext/rosidl_typesupport_connext_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps/fastrtps_cmake_module)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_opensplice/opensplice_cmake_module)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_opensplice/rosidl_typesupport_opensplice_c)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_opensplice/rosidl_typesupport_opensplice_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport/rosidl_typesupport_c)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport/rosidl_typesupport_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz2)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz2/test)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz2/test/tools)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz_assimp_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz_common)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz_default_plugins)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz_ogre_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz_rendering)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz_rendering_tests)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz/src)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz/src/image_view)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz/src/python_bindings)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz/src/python_bindings/shiboken)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz/src/python_bindings/sip)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz/src/rviz)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz/src/rviz/default_plugin)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz/src/test)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/rviz/rviz_visual_testing_framework)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/sros2/sros2_cmake)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/system_tests/test_cli)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/system_tests/test_cli_remapping)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/system_tests/test_communication)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/system_tests/test_rclcpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/system_tests/test_security)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/tinydir_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/tinyxml2_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/tinyxml_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/tlsf/tlsf)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/unique_identifier_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/urdfdom)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/urdfdom/urdf_parser)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/urdfdom/urdf_parser/test)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/urdfdom/urdf_parser/test/gtest)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/urdf/urdf)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/urdf/urdf_parser_plugin)
add_subdirectory(src/ros2/yaml_cpp_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/class_loader)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/class_loader/test)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/class_loader/test/fviz_case_study)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-perception/laser_geometry)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-planning/navigation_msgs/map_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-planning/navigation_msgs/move_base_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/pluginlib/pluginlib)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/resource_retriever/libcurl_vendor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/resource_retriever/resource_retriever)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/resource_retriever/resource_retriever/test)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/ros_environment)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/urdfdom_headers)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/urdfdom_headers/urdf_exception)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/urdfdom_headers/urdf_model)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/urdfdom_headers/urdf_model_state)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/urdfdom_headers/urdf_sensor)
add_subdirectory(src/ros/urdfdom_headers/urdf_world)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_dotgraph)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_gui)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_app)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_core)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp_sip)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_py_common)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt_console)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt_msg)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt_plot)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt_publisher)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt_py_console)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt/rqt_gui_cpp)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt/rqt_py_common)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt_service_caller)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt_shell)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt_srv)
add_subdirectory(src/ros-visualization/rqt_top)
```

... and then I place this file in my ROS2 workspace (Appropriately named, ros2_ws):

```
jhassold@jhassold-ThinkPad-P52:~/ros2_ws$ ls .
build  CMakeLists.txt  install  log  ros2.repos  src
```

I'm then asked to comment out a line in src/ament/ament_cmake/ament_cmake_core/ament_cmake_uninstall_target-extras.cmake, so now my file looks like:

```
# Copyright 2015 Open Source Robotics Foundation, Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# copied from ament_cmake_core/ament_cmake_uninstall_target-extras.cmake

option(AMENT_CMAKE_UNINSTALL_TARGET
  "Generate an uninstall target to revert the effects of the install step" ON)

if(AMENT_CMAKE_UNINSTALL_TARGET)
  include(
    "${ament_cmake_core_DIR}/uninstall_target/ament_cmake_uninstall_target_append_uninstall_code.cmake")

  # create the install script from the template
  # ament_cmake_core/uninstall_target/ament_cmake_uninstall_target.cmake.in
  set(AMENT_CMAKE_UNINSTALL_TARGET_UNINSTALL_SCRIPT
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ament_cmake_uninstall_target/ament_cmake_uninstall_target.cmake")
  configure_file(
    "${ament_cmake_core_DIR}/uninstall_target/ament_cmake_uninstall_target.cmake.in"
    "${AMENT_CMAKE_UNINSTALL_TARGET_UNINSTALL_SCRIPT}"
    @ONLY
  )

  # register uninstall target to run generated CMake script
# add_custom_target(uninstall
#   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P "${AMENT_CMAKE_UNINSTALL_TARGET_UNINSTALL_SCRIPT}")
endif()
```

After this, I divert from the guide a little bit. I do not have a file called ~/ros2_ws/build/rclcpp/cmake_build.sh, so I use the following commands to start CLion (stored in an .sh file, and called by the .desktop file for CLion):

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/ros2_ws/install/local_setup.sh
sh ~/CLion/CLion-2018.3.4/clion-2018.3.4/bin/clion.sh
```

I also do not disable BUILD_TESTING since I thought that I was supposed to have BUILD_TESTING enabled when developing for ROS.

Lastly, I reload the CMake project in ros2_ws, and get the following output:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/jhassold/ros2_ws
-- Found ament_cmake: 0.6.0 (/home/jhassold/ros2_ws/install/share/ament_cmake/cmake)
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Configuring Fast CDR
-- Version: 1.0.8
-- To change de version modify the file configure.ac
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:5 (add_subdirectory):
  Policy CMP0013 is not set: Duplicate binary directories are not allowed.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0013" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The binary directory

    /home/jhassold/ros2_ws/build/src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp

  is already used to build a source directory.  This command uses it to build
  source directory

    /home/jhassold/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp

  which can generate conflicting build files.  CMake does not support this
  use case but it used to work accidentally and is being allowed for
  compatibility.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:15 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/jhassold/ros2_ws/cmake/dev/set_sources.cmake


CMake Error at src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:16 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/jhassold/ros2_ws/cmake/dev/generate_msvc_libraries.cmake


CMake Error: File /home/jhassold/ros2_ws/include/Project/config.h.in does not exist.
CMake Error at src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:29 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file


CMake Error at src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:52 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.


CMake Error at src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:53 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.


CMake Error: File /home/jhassold/ros2_ws/cmake/packaging/Config.cmake.in does not exist.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.cmake:312 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:181 (configure_package_config_file)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/WriteBasicConfigVersionFile.cmake:40 (message):
  No VERSION specified for WRITE_BASIC_CONFIG_VERSION_FILE()
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.cmake:207 (write_basic_config_version_file)
  src/eProsima/Fast-CDR/src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:186 (write_basic_package_version_file)


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jhassold/ros2_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

[Finished]
```

I'm at a loss. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but for the life of me I just can't find it. If anyone has any leads on where to go from here, I'd greatly appreciate it. And hopefully this will help anyone else that's trying to get CLion and ROS2 to work with eachother.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319753/unable-to-load-ros2-workspace-into-clion/) by [jhassold](https://answers.ros.org/users/40639/jhassold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2019-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After significant fighting, I have not been able to successfully get the entire workspace into CLion. However, you can still work with packages individually by opening their respective CMakeLists.txt files as projects.

It's theoretically possible to open the entire workspace if there's a top-level CMakeLists.txt file. But I'm not sure how feasible that is to implement, given the amount of trouble I've had with it.

---

Originally posted by [jhassold](https://answers.ros.org/users/40639/jhassold/) with karma: 50 on 2019-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would not want to compile the ROS2 core using this, but I compile my own workspace of ROS2 nodes using this CMakeLists.txt file in my workspace root. It finds sub-projects automatically like colcon does. You will have to setup the CLion build and run environment variables created using the source /install.bash workspace overlay scripts. See far below, I also created a bash script to print out all the env vars from a properly setup shell so I can then just copy/paste into CLion.

I also have CLion developing ROS nodes on an RPI remotely from my desktop linux using the remote-ssh toolchain. Just generate your env vars from the RPi instead of local system and this works great.

FYI I didnt write this CMakeLists.txt, so I don't deserve any credit for it. :)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project("MyROSProject")

# usually I put this in a separate file include("/opt/ros/_common/Colcon.cmake")
function(colcon_add_subdirectories)
  cmake_parse_arguments(PARSE_ARGV 0 "ARG" "" "BUILD_BASE;BASE_PATHS" "")

  message("search criteria: ${ARGV}")

  execute_process(COMMAND colcon list
        --paths-only
        --base-paths ${ARG_BASE_PATHS}
        --topological-order
        ${ARG_UNPARSED_ARGUMENTS}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE paths)
  string(STRIP "${paths}" paths)
  string(REPLACE "\n" ";" paths "${paths}")

  MESSAGE("colcon shows paths ${paths}")

  foreach(path IN LISTS paths)
    message("...examining ${path}")
    # if(EXISTS "${path}/CMakeLists.txt")
    execute_process(COMMAND colcon info --paths "${path}" OUTPUT_VARIABLE package_info)
    if(NOT "${package_info}" MATCHES "type:[ \t]+(cmake|ros.ament_cmake|ros.cmake)")
      message("skipping non-cmake project")
    elseif(NOT "${package_info}" MATCHES "name:[ \t]+([^ \r\n\t]*)")
      message(WARNING "could not identify package at ${path}")
    else()
      set(name "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
      message("...adding package ${name} from path ${path}")
      MESSAGE("package info: ${package_info}")

      get_filename_component(BUILD_PATH "${name}" ABSOLUTE BASE_DIR "${ARG_BUILD_BASE}")

      add_subdirectory("${path}" "${BUILD_PATH}")
    endif()
  endforeach()
endfunction()

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/humanoid/cmake" CACHE STRING "Modules for CMake" FORCE)

colcon_add_subdirectories(
        BUILD_BASE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/humanoid/build"
        BASE_PATHS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/humanoid/lib/"
        --packages-select LynxmotionLSS
)

colcon_add_subdirectories(
    BUILD_BASE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/humanoid/build"
    BASE_PATHS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/humanoid/src/"
    --packages-select humanoid_model_msgs lss_joint_publisher humanoid_dynamic_model
)
```

You could just setup Workspace overlays, then run CLion bin, or modify your project to include the required env vars. Use this bash script for echo'ing the ROS2 related env vars needed in CLion:

```
 ros_env="AMENT_PREFIX_PATH CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH COLCON_PREFIX_PATH PKG_CONFIG_PATH PYTHONPATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH ROS_DISTRO ROS_PYTHON_VERSION ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY ROS_VERSION"
 for e in ${ros_env}; do
     echo "$e=${!e}"
 done
```

These ENV settings must be pasted into 2 locations in CLion, once for building and then for each program executable runtime environment:

- File | Settings... | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake into the Environment editor dialog
  (now refresh CMake project)
- Run | Edit Configurations... |  | Environment variables editor dialog

---

Originally posted by [guru_florida](https://answers.ros.org/users/49713/guru_florida/) with karma: 280 on 2020-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1